# How do I calculate the average of a linked list recursively?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

This is a java code where I'm supposed to add up the even numbers of a linked list using recursion. This is what I came up with but It's not working out. My java compiler sort of goes to an infinite loop at this statement:          ave(i.getNext());

```
    public double ave (Node b)
 {
    Node i = head;
     if (i == null)
         return 0;

     else 
    {
        if (i.getData()%2==0)
        {
            sum = i.getData() + sum;
            count++;
        }
        if (i.getNext() != null)
        ave(i.getNext()); 

     return sum/(double)count;
 }
```

Comment: You're calling i.getNext() twice. This way you lose every 2nd value. Store in a variable once, then check twice.

Comment: And the real problem is that for recursive functions, you usually need two functions, one that starts the process, and the recursive one. You problem is that 'Node i = head;' will always start from the first element on, thus producing an endless loop

Comment: @JayC667 it's a linked list and he isn't popping them off of a data structure. So, that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: @JayC667 gotcha. I've definitely caused myself a few headaches from popping an element off the top of a stack too many times, though. Something to look out for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning `i` to `head` every time. `b` is never used!

You want:

```
public double ave() {
    return aveRec(head, 0, 0);
}

private double aveRec(Node n, long sum, int count) {
    if (n == null) {
        if (count == 0) {
            // what to return if the linked list is empty?
            return 0;
        }
        return (sum * 1D) / count;
    }
    if (n.getData() % 2 == 0) {
        return aveRec(n.getNext(), sum + n.getData(), count + 1);
    } else {
        return aveRec(n.getNext(), sum, count);
    }

}
```